# How to pass the value from one load statement into another load statement in pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, udf

Hi i have two load statements A and B.I want to pass the particular column values from A to B .I tried the following code.

```
A = LOAD '/user/bangalore/part-m-00000-bangalore' using PigStorage ('\t') as (generatekey:chararray,PropertyID:chararray,ssk:chararray,ptsk:chararray,ptid:chararray,BuiltUpArea:chararray,Price:chararray,pn:chararray,NoOfBedRooms:chararray,NoOfBathRooms:chararray,balconies:chararray,Furnished:chararray,TowerNo:chararray,NoOfTowers:chararray,UnitsOntheFloor:chararray,FloorNoOfProperty:chararray,TotalFloors:chararray,NumberOfLifts:chararray,Facing:chararray,Description:chararray,NewResale:chararray,Possession:chararray,Age:chararray,Ownership:chararray,Type:chararray,PropertyAddress:chararray,Property_Address2:chararray,city:chararray,state:chararray,Property_PinCode:chararray,Locality:chararray,Landmark:chararray,PropertyFeatures:chararray,NearByFacilities:chararray,ReferenceURL:chararray,Flooring:chararray,OverLooking:chararray,ListedOn:chararray,Sellerinfo:chararray,CompanyAddress:chararray,Agency_Address2:chararray,city2:chararray,state2:chararray,Agency_Pincode:chararray,Agency_Phone1:chararray,Agency_Phone2:chararray,ContactName:chararray,Agency_Email:chararray,Agency_WebSite:chararray);

B = foreach A generate Locality;

C = LOAD '/user/april_data/bangalore' using PigStorage ('\t') as (SourceWebSite:chararray,PropertyID:chararray,ListedOn:chararray,ContactName:chararray,TotalViews:int,Price:chararray,PriceperArea:chararray,NoOfBedRooms:int,NoOfBathRooms:int,FloorNoOfProperty:chararray,TotalFloors:int,Possession:chararray,BuiltUpArea:chararray,Furnished:chararray,Ownership:chararray,NewResale:chararray,Facing:chararray,title:chararray,PropertyAddress:chararray,NearByFacilities:chararray,PropertyFeatures:chararray,Sellerinfo:chararray,Description:chararray,emp:chararray);

D = FORACH C generate title

E = join B by Locality,D by title;
```

the locality column is empty.I want to pass the values from the title column to locality column.the above code prints null only.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand. So B only contains NULL entries? In that case the join cannot work. You need a column in B and D that contains matching entries in order to make the join work.

Comment: @illakya : join on the common field between alias : A and C and then after join you can populate the values to locality field. Is there any field between A and C having common values ?